Does this site welcome questions asking for suggestions on which academic programme one must choose?
Yesterday I ran into this question which was asking for suggestions on which institution to choose for psychoanalytic training, and I have the impression that about a month ago I saw a similar question, although this was for an institution providing a cognitive scientific graduate course. I couldn't find the latter question for some reason but don't take my word on its existence in this site. I may have found it elsewhere. 
Nevertheless, my question is if this kind of questions are welcome here. I can imagine that such questions may fall under the category of subjective and that a suggestion from a user may stem from a commercial rather than a scientific interest. However, I am wondering if a discussion on certain features of institutions like the courses taken or research opportunities that would be most suitable for a person with certain research interests, would be useful to some extent.

Judging from the close and down votes, I think our community does not feel it belongs here. I already asked the Academia mods whether they are interested in the question. However, it is good you raise this topic, I don't have time to go through related meta questions here now, but you might be the first to address this issue.

Academia does not want it.

@StevenJeuris Academia doesn't want this'n, or doesn't want such questions in general?  (I had the same question about the same question!)

@Krysta, they don't want too specific questions like this. They are too personalized.

Gottit, good to know.

My understanding is that asking for personal advice in general is off-topic across the Stack Exchange (eg, Meta, Academia, Workplace, Math, and Psychology).
The Stack Exchange is focused on questions that could be of general interest (so not personalized), and is designed for objective answers (so not opinion-based), rather than discussions.  Add to this the dubious value of seeking personal advice from unvetted anonymous users, and you see why such questions are discouraged.
Objective general questions about academic program or career path details may be better suited for Academia.SE or Workplace.SE, but are fine here too.
